# How to compare or prove statistical similarities between two models with differing independent and dependent variables?

Tags: regression, time-series

I have two datasets:

- The relationship between Bitcoin prices and other cryptocurrencies
- The relationship between EUR prices and other currencies

What would be the most appropriate way to prove whether there are similarities between the dependence of the EUR on other currencies and Bitcoin on other cryptocurrencies?

Comment: Over time? Or at a specific snapshot in time? Are there obvious pairings between the real currencies and the cryptocurrencies? More details can help us give a more helpful answer.

Comment: I am currently using the returns of the prices with time-series data and am trying to provide evidence Bitcoin is beginning to behave less like a speculative asset and more like a currency similar to the EUR. From my OLS regression I know both the EUR and Bitcoin are highly correlated with their industries prices. However, I would like to perform further analysis between the relationship each currency has with it's industry and then highlight how this relationship is similar. I hope this helps, thank you

Comment: I think the notion of "similarity" you are looking for is not well-defined. I would suggest looking at existing economics literature on how other types of assets are defined to be "similar" and then see if these similarity methodologies can be extended in this case. This is first and foremost an Economics/Finance question and then a Stats one. Maybe the https://quant.stackexchange.com/ is a better avenue.